# When selecting a select, dynamically assign the value of the input in a dynamic form

Tags: jquery

I return a form in js, where after returning the form I give the possibility to change the select and the input, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upd_orc', function(){
var updo = document.querySelector('input[name="updorc"]:checked').value;
$.getJSON('artigo1.php', function (data2) { 
   $.ajax({  
     url:"updorc1.php",  
     method:"POST",
     cache: false,              
     data:{updo:updo},              
     dataType:"json",  
     success:function(data1){

     var linha1 = ``;
     for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        Ref = data1[i][4];
        Designacao = data1[i][5];

       linha1 += `<div class="teste1">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <select class="form-control1 Referr" name="Refe[]" >
                     <option value="${Ref}">${Ref}</option>`;
                         for (var x = 0; x < data2.length; x++) { 
                             Artigo = data2[x][0];
                             linha1 += `<option value="${Artigo}">${Artigo}</option>`;
                         }
                   linha1 += `</select>
                              <span class="form-highlight"></span>                      
                              <span class="form-bar"></span>                        
                                 <label class="label1" for="Refe">Referência</label>        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control1 desii" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
                    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                    <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
                    </div>
                    </div>`;
                    
                   $("#retorc1").html(linha1);

       }); 
});
});
```

Now I want that when changing the select, automatically assign the value of the input. For this I am doing it this way:

```
$(document).on("change", "select[class*=Referr]", function() {
  var Refart = $(this).val();
  console.log(Refart);
  var selector = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"artigo.php",
        dataType:"Json",
        data:{Refart:Refart},
        success:function(callback){
            var data_array = callback;          
            artigo1 = data_array    
            console.log(artigo1);
            selector.closest(".teste1").find(".desii").val(artigo1);

        }
    }); 
});
```

But when changing the select, it assigns the value to the input according to the select and to all inputs that exist after that input. Those that are previously does not change.

Can you help?

Comment: What do you mean by `all inputs that exist after that input,,` ? Also you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0f8n6udy/) there is no such behaviour .

Comment: @Swati The form I create is dynamic, it can return either 3 lines from the database or 10 lines. So if I change the select of the second line returned, it will assign the value to the input that belongs to that select and to all inputs that are in the lines following that input

Comment: @Swati The problem with my code is that it was missing to close a div, that's why it didn't have the right behavior.